# How to pass C# paramenter in ng-click function

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to do something like that?

```
  <button class="tipbtn" ng-click="callGetInfoBtn($event,@Model.SomeStringProperty)">
```

Comment: Add quotes around them: `callGetInfoBtn($event,'@Model.SomeStringProperty')`

Comment: `"callGetInfoBtn($event,'@Model.SomeStringProperty')"`

Comment: Yes it works, 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it like this:

```
<button class="tipbtn" ng-click="callGetInfoBtn($event, @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SomeStringProperty)))">
```

This will ensure that even if the string property contains some escape characters that could break your javascript (such as single or double quotes) it will be properly formatted.